Не получается сделать так, чтобы на одну учетную запись выдавался один IP адрес в Dante (Danted)
Как сделать так, чтобы в Dante на одну учетную запись выдавался один IP адрес?
Представим, что у меня есть два аккаунта.
И получается так, что если я использую первый аккаунт, я могу подключиться так, что я могу использовать сразу два IP адреса: 11.11.11.11 и 22.22.22.22 (просто подключившись по SOCKS5 к любому из этих IP с одними и теми же данными для авторизации).
Хотя, по идее, у первого аккаунта должен быть доступ только к 11.11.11.11, а у второго - к 22.22.22.22, но не ко всем IP адресам, прикрученным к Dante.
Конфигурация Dante вот:
logoutput: /logs/danted.log
errorlog: /logs/danted.error
internal: 0.0.0.0 port = 1080
external: 11.11.11.11
external: 22.22.22.22
socksmethod: username
user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: nobody
debug: 0
client pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 11.11.11.11/32
    log: connect disconnect error
}

client pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 22.22.22.22/32
    log: connect disconnect error
}

socks pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    log: connect disconnect error
}

Как это сделать/исправить?
